# for loop through folders with specific strings (include and exclude patterns)

Tags: bash, for-loop, glob

I have this piece of code that I am not fully understanding, otherwise I would be able to resolve this issue:

```
shopt -s dotglob extglob nullglob globstar

for imfiles in "$dir"**/@(*-DT-!(*.jpg)|*.fff); do
   printf "File processed: ${imfiles}\n"
done
```

I am trying to include strings -DT-, _CN_, and *.fff but not *.jpg. I do not know how to add the _CN_ so that the for would only process the -DT- and _CN_ and *.fff. I have read the glob - [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) but still cannot figure it out after several attempts. I would appreciate some help with explanation as to what the added code is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use brace expansion for `-DT-` and `_CN_`.

To prevent repeating the `*.fff` matches, put that into a separate argument.

```
for imfiles in "$dir"/**/*{-DT-,_CN_}!(*.jpg) "$dir"/**/*.fff ; do
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried but it didn't work with the brace expansion.

Comment: You also need a `/` before `**` to match recursively.

Comment: I've tested this, it works.

Comment: Thank you Barma. It does process the files twice and picks up files that do not have the _CN_ pattern. Not sure why. Could you tell me what the * in front of the *{-DT-,_CN_} does?

Comment: It matches the beginning of the filename, just like the `*` in your pattern `*-DT-`

Comment: You're right, it picks up the `*.fff` files twice, because the brace expansion causes it to be processed as two wildcards, one with `-DT-` and the other with `_CN_`, and they both include `*.fff`. Better is to split that out separately. I've updated the answer.